# hide html element with the space it takes

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I know my question has been asked many times here.
However, I'm really stuck on this for 2 days now !
I tried all the possible ways and codes to remove the space of a hidden element but I'm not able to.
I have a wordpress website .. with pos plugin .. I need to make changes to this pos ..
I wanted to hide only one thing there .. and I was able to .. but it still takes a space which leaves a big space between the two other elements.

[image]

and this is the css I added to try to hide the blank

```
#products .app-item-details{


height: 0px !important; 
min-height: 0px !important;
min-width: 0px !important;
width: 0px !important;
display: none !important;
 transform: translate(-999px, 0px);

}

#products .app-item-container[_ngcontent-c27] {
    
     translate: -100px !important;
    display: none !important;
    
}

#products .mat-grid-tile .ng-star-inserted {
    
    
   
    left: 0px;
    width: calc((0% - 0.75px) * 1 + 0px) !important;
    top: 0px;
    height: calc(0px) !important;
}
}

#products .app-item-container[_ngcontent-c27] {
    width: 0px !important;
    height: 0px !important;
    padding: 0px !important;
}


#products .mat-grid-tile {
    display: none !important;
    max-width: 0px !important;
}
```

this the link:
https://goldenfish.website/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-openpos/pos/dashboard

you can even login using this temporary user:
username: goldenfish
pass: G0ldEnf!s78052

Comment: I presume its some kind of framework, all the positions are calculated. .mad-grid-tile shows position is absolute. You have to rebuild the grid, with the elements you want to show.

Comment: thanks for the reply. Any idea on how to rebuild it ?